# Spring boot, entity cached issue?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using a PostgreSQL db in the background and Spring Boot with Spring Data.

I have a @Controller that;

1. Calls a Service layer method that has an @Transactional(readOnly = false) on it. This method builds an Entity object from scratch and saves it to the db using the Spring Data built in entityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
2. Then calls via a RestTemplate a remote API that shares the same database, passing the generate Id of the previously saved Entity. This server does some legacy processing and updates the database values.
3. Calls a Service layer method that reads the previously saved Entity and finally returns that as the response to the overall Request.

The trouble is, the changes made by the remote API in step 2 aren't reflected in the db get from step 3.

The @Transaction is only around step 1 so I would have assumed, particularly with the saveAndFlush call, that the transaction ends as that method is exited?

I can call another @Controller method to just perform step 3 afterwards and the result is perfect with the changes from the remote API reflected fine.

It seems that Spring Boot/Data is somewhere caching the result of the initial save for the entire Request, which is not what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the effects of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter keeping the EntityManager bound to your request for the duration of all 3 steps. The EntityManager in your request is oblivious to the database changes you make in step 2.

Assuming you don't have any race conditions (i.e, step 3 runs before step finishes), you could evict the entity cache.

```
// inject the entityManager into a custom repository, and
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(YourEntity.class, id)
```

Comment: While this answer lead me down the right path, I found it simpler to just refresh the object in question with entityManager.refresh(obj);